# UIButton's text is not centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi I have an simple application where I am supposed to change the frame of a UIButton based on its super view and based on its frame the title size should get change.

I am using Autolayout to change the frame of that UIButton. But not getting any idea how to change the font size of that UIButton.

[image: Landscape mode, working as expeted]
[image: Portrait mode, the size of font and button s getting changed but the contents are not centered. This is my issue]

Here is the code I have tried so far.

```
1. [self.cButton sizeToFit] ;

2. [self.cButton.titleLabel sizeToFit] ;

3. self.cButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter ;

4. self.cButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

5. self.cButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter ;

6. self.cButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Like I have tried many things.

Can anyone tell me if I am missing something here and I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Please provide a clear problem statement. What exactly is the desired outcome? What is right / wrong about the two screen shots you posted? And what does any of this have to do with "centered" in your title?

Comment: Have you tried contentVerticalAlignment ?

Comment: I did, but that doesnt matter because vertically it s centered.

Comment: As the title says that the text is not coming in center and my second screen shot shows the issue (the text is not horizontally centered)

Comment: According to the right image. it's not vertically centered.

Comment: It's probably the font. What font are you using?

Comment: Is it possible to make the font size dynamic according to UIButtons frame ?

Comment: @iOS_Developer Very possible.

Comment: Thanks everyone, After going through UILabel class ref, I found this API which helped me a lot but I am yet to make it look better self.cButton.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment =  UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters ;

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and it turned out that I was overriding `layoutSubviews` and had forgotten to call `[super layoutSubviews]`.